# Passing variable to command in git filter-branch (when reducing repo size by removing old binaries)

Tags: macos, git, shell, github

I am looking into ways of reducing repo size by removing binary files. I am writing script that will do this for me, based on http://help.github.com/remove-sensitive-data/

It seems that I have solution working, but somehow I can't pass parameter into nested git command. 
Script with hardcoded file works:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch /*selenium-server-standalone-2.16.0.jar' --prune-empty -- --all 
git push origin master --force 
rm -rf .git/refs/original/ 
git reflog expire --expire=now --all 
git gc --prune=now 
git gc --aggressive --prune=now 
git status
git pull
```

this gives me output

```
Rewrite f9a33e41dd6da4630773272ec18d194d14935a83 (10/10)rm 'bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.16.0.jar'
rm 'selenium-server-standalone-2.16.0.jar'

Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' was rewritten
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
```

but when I try to parametrize this, like below, whole procedure doesn't work

```
fileOLD=selenium-server-standalone-2.16.0.jar
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch /*${fileOLD}' --prune-empty -- --all 
git push origin master --force 
rm -rf .git/refs/original/ 
git reflog expire --expire=now --all 
git gc --prune=now 
git gc --aggressive --prune=now 
git status
git pull
```

output

```
Rewrite 0491bf3461726c2ebd595ebc480010b5bf722302 (1/10)fatal: '/About Administration Tools.app' is outside repository
index filter failed: git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch /*${fileOLD}
```

and it doesn't remove files.

The question is how do I correctly pass/escape variable when passing it into nested git command? (MAC OS x 10.7.2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem are the single quotes (') you use in the git filter. Bash will not replace the variable inside single quotes.

The following should work (untested):

```
fileOLD=selenium-server-standalone-2.16.0.jar
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch /*${fileOLD}" --prune-empty -- --all
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question and @jbraeuer is spot on for your issue involving an `--index-filter`, but I'll add one detail that snagged me up and may help a future reader.

**TLDR;** `--commit-filter` is special. Variables passed to its command must be **exported**.

For most of the filters, e.g., `[--index-filter <command>]`, the `<command>` argument is always evaluated in the shell context using the eval command.

However, for `--commit-filter`, the command is evaluated in a subprocess. Therefore if you need to pass variables into a commit filter command, you **must** **`export`** them before calling `git filter-branch`.

Example where you use a commit filter to generate a log file of old and new sha ids during a filter-branch operation that mucks with the full history of your repo:

```
export _SHA_LOG=<location of log file to create>
_src=<location of .gitattributes and commit hooks to place in your repo history>
_myfilter='echo "${GIT_COMMIT},\c" >> ${_SHA_LOG}; git_commit_non_empty_tree "$@" | tee -a ${_SHA_LOG}'

git filter-branch \
--tree-filter "cp ${_src}/.gitattributes . && cp -r ${_src}/.githooks . && git add --chmod=+x .githooks/* git add . --renormalized" \
--tag-name-filter cat \
--commit-filter "${_myfilter}" -- --all
```